# «Antártida» ou «Antár[c]tica»?

Tags: ortografia, origem-histórica

Fiquei com essa dúvida depois de ler [este artigo](https://pplware.sapo.pt/informacao/um-polo-esta-derreter-vez-gelo) e um comentário:

> O nome do continente gelado que fica no polo sul, muitas vezes me soou
> estranho, eis que recentemente me foi apresentada a teoria que explica
> a origem do nome. Então concluí que “Antártida” está errada.
>
> O polo norte fica na região “ÁRTICA”, então o polo sul fica na região
> anti, contrária, oposta a região ártica, ou seja, anti+ártica =
> ANTÁRTICA.
>
> Conclusão: antártiDa é um erro.
>
> Do artigo mesmo, lê-se em inglês ARTIC e ANTARTIC, em muitos
> dicionários apresentam o latim ARCTICUS e ANTARCTICUS, em francês
> ARCTIQUE e ANTARCTIQUE, em grego ÁRKTIKÓS e ANTÁRKTIKÓS. Então para
> mim, não têm choro, é ANTÁRTICA, nada de escrever com “D”. Parece que
> só existe esse problema do “D” no português e no espanhol.

Vi também na priberam que só tem [«Antárctica»](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/ant%C3%A1rctica) embora diga que é «relativo à Antárctida». Fiz também uma pesquisa no google por [«Antártida»](https://www.google.pt/#newwindow=1&q=antartida) e aparece por todo o lado em sites de notícias e de informação inclusive. Afinal qual das duas é correta? Serão as duas? Também fiquei na dúvida qual a origem destes dois termos e porquê?

> #### an·tárc·ti·co |árt|
>
> (latim antarcticus, -a, -um, meridional, do sul)
> adjectivo
>
> 1. Relativo ao pólo sul ou às regiões próximas do pólo sul; relativo à **Antárctida**.
> 2. Que habita ou está além do círculo polar do sul. = AUSTRAL, MERIDIONAL ≠ ÁRCTICO, BOREAL, SETENTRIONAL

Comment: Francamente, isso se procura na Priberam, Aulete etc.

Comment: A resposta está em https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/ant%C3%A1rctica

Comment: @Lambie fiz uma edição na pergunta, ora veja.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Ambas as formas estão corretas, sendo que atualmente no Brasil ouvimos muito mais "Antártida" do que "Antár(c)tica".** Esta última na maioria das vezes confunde-se com a marca de uma cerveja muito popular no sul do Brasil. Conforme citado pelo OP, a forma correta seria "antárctica", ou seja, "anti-ártico". Mas não sou eu quem dita o uso das palavras e "Antártida" é o que se ouve e o que se lê nos meios de comunicação e nos livros.

O adjetivo, no entanto, continua sendo "antártico(a)" como em "o continente antártico".

> - O topônimo Antártica tem sua origem no latim tardio antarctĭcus que, por sua vez, deriva do grego antigo ανταρκτικός, que significa, literalmente, "oposto ao Ártico" (antiártico). Todavia, convencionalmente adotou-se a forma Antártida, tanto em Portugal como no Brasil, mesmo que contraditória quanto à origem etimológica do topônimo. Uma explicação possível seria a analogia com a mítica Atlântida, algo que ocorre da mesma forma em castelhano, em que também convivem as duas formas, Antártida e Antártica, sendo a primeira de uso mais difundido. Na língua italiana, por sua vez, existe apenas o registro de Antartide, também cunhada sobre o modelo de Atlantide (Atlântida).
> - Em Portugal, antes do Acordo Ortográfico de 1990, a única forma dicionarizada era Antárctida, tomando então o adjetivo a forma antárctico/antárctica (substantivado em [Oceano] Antárctico).
> - No Brasil, a forma convencional era Antártida até meados da década de 1970, quando a forma Antártica passou a ganhar força após ser usada em obras acadêmicas sobre o continente, como o livro Rumo à Antártica da geógrafa Teresinha de Castro, publicado em 1976.    - - From [**Wikipedia**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant%C3%A1rtida#Topon.C3.ADmia)

Comment: Fiz uma edição na pergunta se quiser acrescentar alguma coisa.

Comment: Antártida = continente, Antártica = referente à região antártica

Comment: @AndréLyra     Já consta na resposta que o adjetivo continua sendo "antártica" ou "antártico" , com letra minúscula, como em "o continente antártico".

Comment: Região Antártica, Região Ártica; Polo Antártico, Polo Ártico; o Ártico para Polo Ártico; a Antártica para Região Antártica; não se usa a Ártica, nem o Antártico